# Derived categories of curves equivalent then the curves are isomorphic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra

I am a beginner at derived categories and I'm looking for a proof of the following fact:

If $X$ and $Y$ are smooth projective curves such that $D^b(Coh\,X)$ is equivalent to $D^b(Coh\,Y)$ then $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic.

Can anyone give me the explanation of this fact or provide a good reference for this?

As I understand, the crucial point here is that any object in $D^b(Coh \, X)$ splits as a sum of its cohomology sheaves but I don't know how to finish the proof.

Thank you.

Comment: If either $X$ or $Y$ has genus not equal to $1$ then this follows by the Bondal-Orlov reconstruction theorem (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Bondal-Orlov+reconstruction+theorem). In the genus $0$ case there may or may not be interesting Fourier-Mukai transforms one can write down; I don't know.

Comment: Crosspost: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/177635/derived-categories-of-curves-equivalent-then-the-curves-are-isomorphic